# How to convert std::chrono::time_point to uint64_t?

Tags: c++, c++11, timestamp, c++-chrono, uint64

I am trying to see whether my data is 120 second (or 2 minutes) old or not by looking at the timestamp of the data so I have below code as I am using `chrono` package in C++:

```
uint64_t now = duration_cast<milliseconds>(steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
// check for 2 minutes old data
bool is_old = (120 * 1000 < (now - data_holder->getTimestamp()));   

uint64_t value = now;
while (now < data_holder->getTimestamp() + 80 * 1000 
        && now < value + 80 * 1000) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    now = duration_cast<milliseconds>(steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
}
```

In the above code `data_holder->getTimestamp()` is uint64_t which returns timestamp in milliseconds.

Now when I print out `now` variable value, I see this `10011360` and when I print out `data_holder->getTimestamp()` value which is `1437520382241`

```
2015-07-21 16:13:02,530 WARN 0x7f35312d1700 data_check - now value: 10011360 , data holder timestamp: 1437520382241
```

And from the above data holder timestamp, it doesn't look to be 120 second old data right so I feel something is wrong in my code? Since if I convert that data holder timestamp to actual time (using epoch converter) and then compare it with logs time as shown above it is almost same.

So I decided to use `system_clock` instead of `steady_clock` and came up with below code in which I started to use `auto` instead of `uint64_t`.

**Solution A:**

```
auto now = system_clock::now();
auto dh_ts = system_clock::time_point{milliseconds{data_holder->getTimestamp()}};
bool is_old = (minutes{2} < (now - dh_ts));
```

Earlier, I was using `now` variable value as `uint64_t` instead of `auto`. Now after the above code, I have something like this in my original code since `now` is not `uint64_t` so I am getting compilation error while compiling the code.

```
uint64_t value = now;
while (now < data_holder->getTimestamp() + 80 * 1000 
        && now < value + 80 * 1000) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    now = duration_cast<milliseconds>(steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
}
```

What is the right way to fix this? I cannot change `data_holder->getTimestamp()` data type, it has to be `uint64_t` since other code is also using it.

Here is the error:

```
error: cannot convert std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >â to âuint64_t {aka long unsigned int}â in initialization
```

**UPDATE:**

Can I use like this instead of using `Solution A` if everything looks good below?

**Solution B:**

```
uint64_t now = duration_cast<milliseconds>(system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
bool is_old = (120 * 1000 < (now - data_holder->getTimestamp()));
```

Comment: so, your `while` loop condition consists of 8 operators and a function call.  And it involves magic numbers.  Complex code that works is marginally ok: complex code that doesn't work should be made less complex.  (and no, I don't care if that particular line works, its existence detracts from debugging the rest of the nearby code).  I don't see where you set `getTimeStamp`'s data -- what epoch is it using, and how do you know it is the same one as the clock you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I would suggest going more in the direction of solution A and converting the rest of your `uint64_t` times into time_points: the `chrono` unit system is pretty useful. I would start by defining a helper function to convert from the `uint64_t` timestamps on your objects to time_points:

```
using u64_millis = duration<uint64_t, milli>;
static time_point<system_clock, u64_millis> u64_to_time(uint64_t timestamp) {
    return time_point<system_clock, u64_millis>{u64_millis{timestamp}};
}
```

if your epoch is different than the one for `system_clock`, this would be the place to fix it. It would probably also work to use `milliseconds` instead of `u64_millis`, but the representation type for `milliseconds` isn't explicitly defined and doing it the above way ensures that the types match up correctly.

Now, the code that you posted becomes something like:

```
auto now = system_clock::now();
bool is_old = now - u64_to_time(data_holder->getTimestamp()) > minutes{2};

auto value = now;
while (now - u64_to_time(data_holder->getTimestamp()) < seconds{80}
        && now - value < seconds{80}) {
    this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds{100});
    now = system_clock::now();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

At least as I read it, this is sleeping 100 ms at a time, then checking whether it's slept for 2 minutes yet. Then repeating until it reaches the 2 minute point.

It seems to me like it makes a lot more sense to compute the desired time, and sleep until then:

```
struct foo { 
    time_point<system_clock> time_stamp;

    time_point<system_clock> get_timestamp() { return time_stamp; }
    foo() : time_stamp(system_clock::now()) {}
};

// ...    
foo f;

std::this_thread::sleep_until(f.get_timestamp() + 2m);
```

This does use the (new in C++14) user defined literal to construct a duration of 2 minutes. If you really need to support an older (C++11) compiler, you'll need to use `minutes(2)` instead.

As far as the title question goes, I'd say: just say no. Far better to store your time_points as actual time_points than insist on stuffing them into integers, then turn them back into time_points when you need to use them again. It's not at all apparent that this accomplishes anything useful in exchange for the pain.